# Customize UI for game kit

Tags: iphone, gamekit

I am using game center for my game, I want to create my own UI for authentication and other screen rather than provide built in UI.

So can we use customize UI for leaderboard or authentication screen?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. Additionally I haven't seen any app with a custom UI for this.